# Hifumi vs Ichi Ni San

Tags: words, etymology, numbers

`一二三` in Japanese is read as `ichi ni san` to mean, `one two three`.

But it can also be read as `hifumi`. What does `hifumi` mean?

From http://quest-for-japan.com/others/one-to-ten-in-japanese-2/ , it says it could be a name.

There are also manga characters which abbreviated to `hi-fu-mi` too (http://change-123.wikia.com/wiki/HiFuMi)

But what does `hifumi` actually mean? Where does it come from?

Comment: Your assumption is that いち・に・さん comes from Japan, right?  If so, you are already wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So do you know ひとつ, ふたつ, みっつ and so on, the "traditional Japanese" version of counting one to ten? "ひ, ふ, み, ..." (or "ひい, ふう, みい, ...") is just an abbreviated version of this, and is occasionally used by some (older) people to count things with fingers.

Today, ひふみ is also known as a rare Japanese person name (both as a first name and a last name). [Hifumi Kato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hifumi_Kat%C5%8D) is the only real example I knew, but there is [a real baseball player whose last name is Hifumi](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%80%E4%BA%8C%E4%B8%89%E6%85%8E%E5%A4%AA). Hifumi is probably more commonly found in fiction, for example [Hifumi Yamada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Danganronpa_characters#Danganronpa:_Trigger_Happy_Havoc.5B1.5D) and [Hifumi Takimoto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Game!#Characters) are relatively recent examples. Its "meaning" is nothing but "one-two-three", but since this is an established proper noun, its meaning is no longer important.